# Add blur effect to images in drupal 7?

Tags: media

basically I want to add the ability to add a blur effect style to the image styles in Drupal 7.

I tried the [imageCache custom action module](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) but I am not able to add own php code since saving any code causes an error. Ive read that people guess the module itself seems to be buggy.

Is there any way I can add my own effect, a function like those listed in image.inc and add that effect to the dropdown?

EDIT:

thanks to the help of Clive I've actually managed to add a blur effect - wicked! :)

Here's the code:

```
function image_blur_image_effect_info() {

    return array(
        'image_blur' => array(
            'label' => t('Gaussian Blur'),
            'help' => t('Gaussian blur the image by a given amount.'),
            'effect callback' => 'image_blur_gaussian_blur'
        )
    );
}

function image_blur_gaussian_blur(stdClass $image) {
    $amount = 30;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
        imagefilter($image->resource, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
    }

    return imagefilter($image->resource, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
}
```

I just wondered whether this could be done nicer somehow?

Next question: Is it possible to add an input field once the effect is selected sothat the user can type a custom amount of blurriness?

Like so:

```
function image_blur_gaussian_blur(stdClass $image, $CUSTOMAMOUNT) {
    $amount = $CUSTOMAMOUNT;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
        imagefilter($image->resource, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
    }

    return imagefilter($image->resource, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you'll need to write a custom module and implement [`hook_image_effect_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.api.php/function/hook_image_effect_info/7) to register your effect with the system, e.g.:

```
function MYMODULE_image_effect_info() {
  return array(
    'mymodule_blur' => array(
      'label' => t('Blur'), 
      'help' => t('Blur an image.'), 
      'effect callback' => 'mymodule_blur_effect',
    )
  );
}
```

Then implement your callback function (`mymodule_blur_effect()`) to manipulate the image. Try following the function trail from [`image_resize()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21image.inc/function/image_resize/7) to get some inspiration on exactly how to access the image stream data.

Comment: wow, thanks for your super fast reply! do i really have to make a module out of that or can i just add those codes to existing files like my template.php?

Comment: Those hooks don't get called for themes unfortunately, it'll have to be a module

Comment: well, i guess ill give it a try. thanks so much :)

Comment: No worries :) The [module developer guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) is a good place to start if you haven't written a module before...it's pretty easy though

Comment: Hey Clive, thanks for your help, I managed it! :) Could you have a look at the next question in the first post? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of modules that are probably worth experimenting with:  [FiltersIE](https://www.drupal.org/project/filtersie) and [Image effect kit](https://www.drupal.org/project/iek).